# What is the antonym of register?

Tags: antonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Unregister” vs “Deregister”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25931/unregister-vs-deregister)

I'm just wondering what the consensus would be on the antonym of register. The intended use of the word is for a website. Users can register for the site, and should they desire, they can also "unregister".

Can you list a set of words that would fit the problem domain?

Comment: I didn't downvote this question, but I'd like to know if that was done simply because OP didn't do a quick search and find the existing question before posing it again.

Comment: I don't know, but people are actually practicing "pity voting". Should we increase the rep limit when you can finally upvote?

Comment: Here are my search terms: 

[What is the antonym of register](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=what+is+the+antonym++of+register) 
[What is the opposite of register](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=what+is+the+opposite+of+register)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are several words including "cancel", "eradicate", "rescind", but I think the most relevant word is:

> Deregister

Taken from [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25931/unregister-vs-deregister)

Comment: I don't really understand the rationale for actually answering this question here. Why isn't it better to just let OP follow the "possible duplicate" link, and leave it at that?

Comment: Haha! Um... save him the trouble?

Comment: Um... in the absence of your answer OP's effort would actually be *less*, I feel. He'd have only *one* link to click on, so no time wasted scrolling down, finding the other link in your answer, deciding which to go for, etc. Not to mention the extra click to *Accept* your answer. But surely you didn't do it just to pick up a bit more rep?

Comment: My Goodness!! the things you imply!!

Comment: No seriously - I think early on some people worry about getting more rep because the lack of it can be restrictive. But I'm taking it for granted you & I are at a level where that's pretty irrelevant. Personally I don't even understand all the things I can do already, so I'm hardly falling over myself to pass the 5000 mark and have some new exotic capability that I ought to sit and figure out how to use wisely. Parochially, perhaps, I just assume anyone with a similar rep to mine feels much as I do about it.

Comment: Ah, well, some people are wiser, some are not. I'm a bit childish myself. Love those reps!!!

Comment: btw - my screen didn't update until after I wrote **etc** in my second comment above, at which I was quite surprised to see OP had actually *accepted* your answer. My potentially (but not really lol) snarky final sentence was really just because I thought it was odd that he would do that.

Comment: whatever floats your boat. I'm now going to go out on a limb and downvote the question lol

Comment: That's another extra click...!

Comment: Being the wrong side of 50, I'm happy to do that extra click if it helps keep the digits nimble and stave off the onset of arthritis lol

Comment: Now I understand your name!!

Comment: @Fumble @Ham Downvoting increases the downvotee's rep. I see that a question or answer has has been downvoted and I give it a vote just to spite the downvoter :p Wonder if i'm alone in that. +1 to question and answer.

Comment: @92MGRXvm...oh whatev...:) Good Strategy! However, if the post truly is terrible, I don't just downvote it - I *flag* it. (in hush undertones)

Comment: @92MGRXvmoFfCkCd1JH4p9jpZjFQRKp: I don't really understand your thinking, but I think it's what the SE designers/mods call "pity upvoting". Which some think should be discouraged by giving negative rep because they don't approve, whereas others say it doesn't happen enough to be an issue. I often downvote questions just because they're not as good as 'average' ones - not because they're so crappy I want to flag them for removal.

Comment: @fumbleFingers, Great reasoning. I see things better now.

Comment: I'm a tireless fifth columnist working to spread my own idiosyncratic foibles throughout .se! Actually, I was under the impression that downvoting *cost* me rep, but I can't imagine it would influence my choice of action whichever way it went. Unless you only ever say really dorky things, rep just keeps creeping up. But I *do* like it when I get another upvote on an answer I gave weeks ago. Makes me feel it's worthwhile spending more time answering as well as possible, knowing your deathless prose really can live on beyond the first day or so.

Comment: ...Applaud... you've just written your fifth essay at the same post!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ham and Bacon found the information I couldn't, he/she solved my problem, therefore I gave him/her the accepted answer. My post is pretty much the same as the one linked to, so the community can do as they wish with it, but that doesn't remove the fact that Ham and Bacon helped me clarify an issue and in my opinion deserves the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm a thon, or a se.

Comment: @Danger Doug: Fair point, except I would say you yourself are a member of the community (and hopefully will become more so over time), so how you use .se affects how it evolves over time. I'm not really arguing anything passionately here - just looking to nudge some thinking towards beefing up the 'permanent knowledge base' aspect of the site. I do realise that runs counter to the 'ephemeral real-time Q&A' aspect which is also one of se's many fine attractors.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You should realize that a few users who come into the site give up on it because of strict religious moderation by the likes of yourself. The site is nothing without its users. I would not bother answer/question on a site where my first action is severely downvoted/criticized. Plus someone would read the FAQ if they want to stick around and not if they are just trying the site out. I understand the greater purpose you have which is to make this question a permanent knowledge base but the larger point is that the site will remain attractive so long as people can use it.

Comment: I think for websites, they just say 'delete account'. I've not seen deregister before.