# antonym of "to register with"

Tags: phrases, antonyms

What is the antonym of the phrase `to register with`? I'm not looking for the antonym of `to register` itself (that's `to deregister`) but for the correct dependent preposition.

For example:

`to register with the provider`

`to deregister with/from/? the provider`

*This is **not** a duplicate of [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25931) or [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28729).*

Comment: Personally I would use *from* (but I would expect to see both in use).

Comment: Both prepositions are used ( see examples in Nram) with *from* the more common between the two. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=deregister+from%2Cderegister+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cderegister%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cderegister%20with%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Josh61 Great, didn't know google's Ngram Viewer. Downvoter: Care to comment? What's wrong with my question?

Comment: Most words don't have antonyms! Register doesn't have one!

Comment: @curiousdannii `register` has one, as indicated by the questions I referenced. I think Josh61's comment answers my question already and I would accept they as an answer.

Comment: @MaxTruxa No, deregister is not the antonym of register. It's a derived word, but it doesn't mean the opposite of register.

Comment: @Josh61 If you would compose an answer that contains basically the same information as your comment I would gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To deregister**  ***with or from***.

> Both preposition are used as clearly shown in [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=deregister%20with%2Cderegister%20from&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cderegister%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cderegister%20from%3B%2Cc0) with *from*  probably more common between the two. It appears there is no real reason to prefer one from the other, it is just a question of personal style.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably recommend *to withdraw from*, depending on the context. Another possibility, again depending on context, might be *to unsubscribe from*.